# Access WCF service from Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight, crm

I am trying to access a WCF service from silverlight application .I have hosted this service in local IIS and checked if that I am getting service correctly but when I try to access it from silverlight I am getting crossdomain error .

I checked few threads on MSDN and stackoverflow placed clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain file in root folder of my IIS but I still get this same error .

can anyone help me out .

Answer (score 0):

If you install a tool like [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) (or any other software that lets you see what requests are made) you can track on which path the policy file needs to be. In most cases you used the wrong directory for the file or there is no request made because it's cached somewhere.

Check if your file is where it is supposed to be. Most likely, it's not.

Comment: I checked on fiddler about this when I open my silverlight application it can access clientaccesspolicy.xml please check at screenshot I just pasted below

http://gyazo.com/36a61a7c27ca331460f9743d1c6b173c

These are the path's where I just placed me .xml files 

C:\inetpub\wwwroot >> Is this the correct path ?

My service file is at this path 

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MTC.NetProspex_deploy >> I tried placing both clientpolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml file here 

Please let me know what mistake I have done here